# error de cargue de contenido back wildfly

Tags: linux, apache, wildfly

Tengo un servidor Alma linux 8 en el cual esta desplegado un apache y wildfly 26. despues de haber desplegado la aplicación. y hablitar el https "ssl" desde el apache este no carga el contenido de back de wild fly.

Teniedo en cuenta estas son las configuraciones de mi httpd

[image: configuracionhttpd]

Los certificados los genere con CERTBOT

Nota: el sitio carga correctamente en https.

Pero al momento de entrar en el navegador el depurador de red me evidencia lo siguiente:

Se ha bloqueado la carga del contenido activo mixto "http://ipservidor:8088/login"

tambien este:

[image: el error que me genera al entrar desde cualquier navegador]